# Misunderstood the usage of cin.unget() while handling I/O files C++

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream, cin

For example, I have a file named `Bjarne.txt` and in it there's the integers:

```
16   2   3   4
```

I have made a program to read the integers available inside the file and output them to me in the console window , however , I'm trying to use `cin.unget()` and by that get understanding of what it does actually , here's the source code:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>      
using namespace std;

int main () {
ifstream ifs("Bjarne.txt");
int a;
for(int i = 0;i<4;++i){
   ifs>>a;
   cout<<endl<<a;
   if(i==0){
   ifs.unget();
   }
}
```

And the output is:

```
16 6 2 3
```

Why is the output like that? ( it should be `16 2 3 4` ) , it only occurs when I put ifs.unget() in the program , so my questions are , what is the purpose of cin.unget() while using I/O files and why is the number 6 ( as part of 16 ) getting outputted?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `cin.unget()` when you have no understanding of what it does? And why did you not read its documentation to find out?

Comment: So, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget)?

> Makes the most recently extracted character available again.

At the end of your first loop iteration, `6` was the last extracted character (as the final digit of the extracted formatted `int` with value `16`).

Unget does exactly that: it un-*gets* it.

The next operation has the `6` to work with. So, surprise, you get `6` next time.

Comment: Let's say I have such code : https://ideone.com/lh9YeA                                 If I input for example " 123456 " , the output would be "123456" , if it were without the cin.unget() , the output would be " 23456 " , therefore , It does not necessarily ( cin.unget() ) make the most recently extracted character available again , but makes the first character available again in the example in the link above, why?

Comment: @zLeon: Because you have a `cin.get()` operation at the start of `main`, that eats up the first digit...... you're not reading your own code mate! `unget` _does_ do exactly what it's advertised to do. The `unget` is _before_ the extraction into `a`, so I don't know what you're talking about with this "first character" business. At the time the `unget` is executed, it _does_ make the most recently extracted character (`1`) available again.